# Winter '16 Community Builder, Live Agent and Content Security Policy issues

Tags: lightning-aura-components, liveagent, customer-community

Because of the Content Security Policy set when using Lightning components there I haven't found a way to include a Live Agent deployment as part of a Community built using the Winter '16 Community Builder. The same issue prevents Google Analytics from working too.

Is there a way around the Content Security Policy when writing Lightning Components?

Answer (score 1):

Not at this time. Please file a bug or enhancement request so that it can be logged and considered.

Comment: Thanks, we're working with the Community product team and security at Salesforce on it. When we get some resolution i'll come back and post it.

Comment: Please see my answer below, a patch has gone out addressing the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A patch went out over the last couple of weeks. There was no communication nor notice ( as far as I know ) about the patch.

However, third party Javascript should now be working in your Lightning-based communities. I have Live Agent and Google Analytics working in a community in a sandbox org.

I really wanted Websockets to work too but it appears the patch did not cover connect-src in the CSP.